# Htaccess - Redirecting root directory to subdirectory without showing the subdirectory URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a www.site.com

I would like to redirect this site to a subdirectory site.com/folder1/folder2/

The URL should still only display www.site.com.

When they click around the site, such as about-us, the URL should show www.site.com/about-us (but really /folder/1/folder2/about-us)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder1/folder2/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!folder1/folder2/).*)$ folder1/folder2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi, I added the above code in the .htaccess file but it still displays the existing files located in the root directory. Am I missing something?

Comment: This redirects to the subdirectory, however the URL displays the full path name as the user clicks on various pages and links. Is there a way to remove that?

Comment: anubhava, is there a way to email you directly? I'm still seeing the subdirectories, and I do have a side question regarding another part of the site that is affected from this htaccess. Where can I reach you?

Comment: My email is `anubhava@aol.com` but I prefer not to answer on side/extended questions. SO practice is to keep answer to the specific question asked. You have already extended problem once.